# XMLHTTPRequest ReadyState issue in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

From my UI thread, I am trying to start a worker thread to do XMLHTTPRequest. It works perfectly in Chrome, but in IE 10 its not working.
In IE its always giving me ReadyState =1, Status=0 and stopping. In chrome the code works perfectly and as expected. Can anybody advise me please what might be wrong here related to one browser?

UI thread code:

```
  if (typeof (Worker) !== "undefined") {
            var w = new Worker("worker.js");
            var now = new Date();
            w.postMessage({
                newid: ws.length,
                starttime: now
            });
```

Below is my worker.js code

```
this.onmessage = function ($event) {
var myid = 0;
var mystarttime = "";
var url = "http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting";

myid = $event.data.newid;
mystarttime = $event.data.starttime;

var gotresponse = function () {
    var rs = new Response();
    if ((xhr.readyState == 4 || xhr.readyState == 3) && xhr.status == 200) {
        var result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        rs.id = myid;
        rs.starttime = mystarttime;
        rs.data = result.content;
        rs.endtime = new Date();
    }
    else {
        rs.err = 'Error.   ReadyState: ' + xhr.readyState + ' Status:' + xhr.status;
    }
    self.postMessage(rs);
    self.close();
};

var timedout = function () {
    var rs = new Response();
    rs.err = 'Error TIMEOUT occurred : ' + xhr.statusText + '  ReadyState: ' + xhr.readyState + ' Status:' + xhr.status + ' E: ' + e + ' Msg:' + e.message;
    rs.starttime = mystarttime;
    rs.data = result.content;
    rs.endtime = new Date();


    self.postMessage(rs);
    self.close();
};

function Response(name, gender) {
    this.id = 0;
    this.data = "";
    this.starttime = new Date();
    this.endtime = new Date();
    this.err = "";
}

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
getSpecData();

function getSpecData() {
    try {
        xhr.onload = function () { console.log(this.responseText); };
        xhr.open('GET', url, false);
        xhr.timeout = 5000;
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        //xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('sk:pwd'));
        xhr.ontimeout = timedout;
        xhr.onreadystatechange = gotresponse;
        //xhr.withCredentials = true;
        xhr.send();
    } catch (e) {
        var rs = new Response();
        rs.err = 'Error occured : ' + xhr.statusText + '  ReadyState: ' + xhr.readyState + ' Status:' + xhr.status + ' E: ' + e + ' Msg:' + e.message;
        self.postMessage(rs);
        self.close();
    }
}
```

};

Comment: OK, try setting a timeout, IE events work differently, execute your code after 500 ms, and check it out, it worked for me once.

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt, sorry but I didn't get your point completely. If you check my code I have already set a timeout of 5000 at the moment. Are you referring to some other timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I meant, add timeout, after the readystatechange event occurs:

```
var gotresponse = function () {

    setTimeout(function(){
    var rs = new Response();
    if ((xhr.readyState == 4 || xhr.readyState == 3) && xhr.status == 200) {
        var result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        rs.id = myid;
        rs.starttime = mystarttime;
        rs.data = result.content;
        rs.endtime = new Date();
    }
    else {
        rs.err = 'Error.   ReadyState: ' + xhr.readyState + ' Status:' + xhr.status;
    }
    self.postMessage(rs);
    self.close();
    },500);

};
```

just give it a try..

Comment: VERY strange! i added this timeout, and it starte working beautifully, BUTTTT, then i removed the timeout code and it STILL continued working. My code was not working for sure since morning and I had tried a lot of permutations, combinations. And now its working even without your timeout fix... seems as if IE had some internal stick-up, which got cleared by using timeout fix of yours once?? This is really making me crazy :p

Comment: yeah I know,it's an issue with IE, as I mentioned.